# To identify repeated strings and obtain them as a list in Python

Tags: python

```
A = "AEJXKWKJSSSJKZJLJLEJLKXMPPLSSKKDNEMSMLDMMEPPLEJSSTFMM"
Repeat_Letter : [PPL, JSS]   --> What I want
```

I want the maximum length of repeated words and get them as a list. For example, if the letter "APPLE" is repeated, not getting a result says AP or APPL is repeated, but hope it is correctly recognized that APPLE is repeated.

Comment: The answer to “is it possible” is almost always “Yes” – you’re using a general-purpose language on a computer that is all but a Turing machine.  The question you may intend to ask, “how do I do it”, is too unfocused for Stack Overflow.  Repeat the intro tour, especially [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Prune I fixed my question thanks to you! Thank you for fixing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, the word to search for is "[trigrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigram)".

For your problem as stated, you can break it into all the 3-letter groups, count them (with `collections.Counter`), then find those that have a count>1.

```
import collections

A = "AEJXKWKJSSSJKZJLJLEJLKXMPPLSSKKDNEMSMLDMMEPPLEJSSTFMM"
trigrams = [A[i:i+3] for i in range(len(A)-2)]
counts = collections.Counter(trigrams)
repeated = [trigram for trigram, count in counts.items() if count > 1]
```

This gives the result: `['JSS', 'LEJ', 'PPL']`